# Identifier sstream is undefined?

Tags: string

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <string>
  #include <sstream>
  using namespace std;
  int main() 
  {
     sstream s(string in);
     
  }
```

I included the sstream class. Any other classes I need to include?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You included the `<sstream>` *header*. There is no `sstream` class.

The header `<sstream>` defines the class `stringstream`.

It can be a bit confusing. Most standard library headers (`<string>`, `<vector>`, etc.) define a class (or class template) with the same name as the header. Some, like `<memory>` and `<algorithms>`, define a bunch of entities that are not organized into a single class. `<sstream>`, which defines `<stringstream>`, is the only case I can think of where the header names is an *abbreviation* of the name of the primary class defined by the header.

For future reference, [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/) is a very good C++ reference. Searching there for `<sstream>` gives you documentation on what's defined in the header.

Comment: I am really dumb. Lol. Thank you!

Comment: @MathWhiz It can be confusing. `<sstream>` / `stringstream` is an exception to the way most standard library headers and classes are named. I've stubbed my metaphorical toe on that one myself. I've expanded my answer.

Comment: So what is the fix?  Don't put `#include <sstream>` at the top?

Comment: @mLstudent33 No, keep the `#include <sstream>`, but refer to the class as `stringstream` rather than `sstream`.